# Deploy azure Storage account using Terraform Cloud from Postman (API)

Tags: azure, terraform, postman, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

Deploy azure storage account using terraform cloud iam able to run it from terraform cloud in which i hav set the variables for resource group and location, so now with the API i have to trigger it from Postman.

The problem here is it is not picking the variable values from postman which im passing, its taking from the variables i have set in the workspace. How to avoid this or give me a solution to this. Below is the main.tf and JSon Body which iam passing it from postman. Thanks In Advance!
main.tf

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.46.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "ResourceGroup" {
  name = "${var.RG_NAME}"
  location = "${var.REGION}"
  
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "test" {
  name                     = "${var.STORAGE_NAME}"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.ResourceGroup.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  
  }
}
```

```
JSON BODY

{
  "data": {
    "attributes": {
      "message": "Triggered by Postman",
      "is-destroy": false,
       "auto-apply": true,
       "env-vars" : {
        "RG_NAME": "tfcloud26",
        "REGION": "eastus",
        "STORAGE_NAME": "tcloudaz26"
       }
       
    },
    "relationships": {
      "workspace": {
        "data": {
          "type": "workspaces",
          "id": "vvvpe8"
        }
      }
    },
    "type": "runs"
    
  }
}
```